# B2C custom policy Change Password "The username or password provided in the request are invalid"

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to implement a password change custom policy for Azure AD B2C.

I've used [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/change-password/policy/PasswordChange.xml) file as a base, changed the tenantid, and uploaded it to Azure.

When I try a demo from the Azure portal, it asks me to log in, then asks for an old password and a new password to change it. And it works perfectly fine. I can change my password there.

Then I've implemented a button, that redirects to the password change URL.

```
private redirectPasswordChange(appConfigService: AppConfigService): void {
  const passwordChangeUrl = `${appConfigService.config.AD_AUTHORITY_CHANGE}?client_id=${appConfigService.config.AD_CLIENT_ID}
    &nonce=defaultNonce
    &redirect_uri=${appConfigService.config.BASE_URL}
    &scope=openid
    &response_type=id_token`;
  if (isPlatformBrowser(PLATFORM_ID)) {
    window.location.href = passwordChangeUrl;
  } else {
    this.window.location.href = passwordChangeUrl;
  }
}
```

I've removed `prompt=login` from the URL because the button that is going to redirect to the password change URL is on the "My profile" section on our website. So users are already logged in, and I don't want them to log in again.

Then I tested it on our website, when I click to button, it redirects me to the password change page, it asks for my old password, new password, and confirmation of it, which is perfect for me. But the problem is, it doesn't accept my old password, it says "The username or password provided in the request are invalid".

[image: password change page]

I've searched for the problem online, including StackOverflow, but I found that there are lots of different answers for this problem. One of them is saying that:

```
Its because these input claims are overwriting the input claim names for login-noninteractive.
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="client_credentials" />
         <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="https://{{tenantID}}.onmicrosoft.com/{{registeredApiAppName}}/.default" />
  </InputClaims>
use different claim names, and use a partnerclaimtype to send the value with the original claim name.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65931145/8831824
```

When I take a look, I can see that those orchestrationsteps on PasswordChange.xml are the same in TrustFrameworkBase.xml

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" /> 
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Is there some kind of overwriting here? I mean, they are exactly the same, but in two different files, In TrustFrameworkBase.xml, for SignUpOrSignIn journey, and PasswordChange.xml, for PasswordChange journey.

Here are the policies I have. I did put great effort to solve the problem, but I couldn't even identify it. Hope someone can give me an idea to work on it. Thanks for reading.

TrustFrameworkBase.xml: https://pastebin.com/RXXhcwpN

TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml: https://pastebin.com/UUfVNaJ7

PasswordChange.xml : https://pastebin.com/sPjZjNYT

PasswordReset.xml :  https://pastebin.com/CxE3pMH3

Comment: Unfortunately the pastebin content is no longer available which undermines the usefulness of this question to others who may be experiencing something similar!

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem, but different from the question author my issue wasn't mixing up user flows with custom policies.

I was 100% sure that the root cause was not misconfiguration of `login-noninteractive` nor `IdentityExperienceFramework` to `ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId` wrong setup as I followed copybook style [ms docs on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

The error cause turns out to be that the property **accessTokenAcceptedVersion** on IdentityExperienceFramework's manifest file was set to `2` instead of `null`.

Setting it to `null` solves the issue.

---

#### Considerations

1. How come this property was set to 2? And why is this a problem

> Most likely because I've created the app initially configured to
> support Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD
> directory - Multitenant) but changed my mind and updated it to
> support Accounts in this organizational directory only (your-tenant
> only - Single tenant) changing the manifest property to look like so:

```
"signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
```

as the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps) states:

> If signInAudience is azureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount, the value (of accessTokenAcceptedVersion) must be 2.

2. How do I spot that issue?

> By automating the environment configuration of an auxiliary B2C tenant by using the https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/ and comparing each of the app's configs.

3. If you've setup IdentityExperienceFramework and ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId manually by following ms docs and still facing this obscure issue:

> I highly recommend you delete your apps and rely on the automated tool. (I've learned my lesson)

Answer (score 1):

Your password change xml should have the base policy node reference the trust framework extensions policy, not the trust framework base policy, as per my sample.

Ultimately the issue is because trust framework base file only contains part of the login-noninteractive technical profile. It is completed in the extension file, hence you must reference a file from which all dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
But isn't it already referencing the trust framework extensions policy?

    `<BasePolicy>
        <TenantId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
        <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
    </BasePolicy>`


Should I move things about login-noninteractive in base policy to the extensions policy?

Comment: I think the issue is to do with the order in which the validation technical profiles are running in `LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId`, as it’s writing the new password, then checking the old password, then writing the new password again. That’s because the VTPs are merged between all files for the same technical profile Id. I am not sure why there is different behaviour when launching from the portal though.

Comment: Our official docs have a more up to date example for this scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: What I realized is, we do use a user flow for sign-in, not a custom policy. 
Can mixing the user flows with custom policies be the problem? 

When I run the password change custom policy from the portal and log in there, it does change my password. When I run it from my application, by removing login=prompt, because I think it is already logged in, it doesn't accept my old password. Could this be because I'm not actually logged in to a custom policy, but a user flow instead?

I will take a look at the official docs. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework has been set up on   TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml. So I don't know what might be the issue here.

Comment: It because of the mix of custom policy and user flow, the email claim used in the session cookie is probably a different claim name, causing the custom policy to not work from your app when using the session (omitting prompt=login). The custom policy will pickup a null claim for email since it’s set in a different claim by user flow. You need to use custom policies all up.

Comment: Okay, to accomplish that, would it work if I download the userflow and just upload it as custom policy? Is this possible? I don't want to upload a clear custom policy from microsofts repo because there are some customizations on the userflow.

Comment: You cannot directly export User Flow to Custom Policy. You can get a head start by deploying the custom policy starter pack through this [tool](https://aka.ms/iefsetup).